# How to decode token and get back information for djangorestframework-jwt packagefor Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have started using djangorestframework-jwt package instead of PyJWT , I just could not know how to decode the incoming token (I know there is verify token methode).... All I need to know is how to decode the token and get back info encoded......

Comment: Why do you need to decode it?

Comment: I have a custom user model and I have added 'userType'  to identify the type of user like subscriber or editor or author something like this.... so when a  api request is made to the endpoint based on the userType the response varies... So I had encoded userType on token and when request is made by decoding it I would be able to identify the type of the user...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May be its too late to answer, but we can decode jwt and get our payload back
using jwt.decode from jwt module

Assume that jwt token you get looks like and your encrypted payload lies in middle of the token

```
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MzIxMzg3ODQsImV4cCI6MTUzMjEzOTA4NCwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmF0aWsucHVjc2RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwibXlmIjoxfQ.enG5qiSOPh98YYZBpScHSL5TM8RBz6JhU6uF0l1bZXM"
}
```

Following is snippet for solution:

```
import jwt
#jwt.decode(<encoded token>,<secret key>,<algorthm>)
decodedPayload = jwt.decode('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MzIxMzg3ODQsImV4cCI6MTUzMjEzOTA4NCwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmF0aWsucHVjc2RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwibXlmIjoxfQ.enG5qiSOPh98YYZBpScHSL5TM8RBz6JhU6uF0l1bZXM',None,None)
```

Answer (score 15):

I use this method to decode tokens and verify the user. First I used without `algorithms=['HS256']` then it gives jwt.exceptions.DecodeError. Finally, I added it. Folwing methos worked fine for me.

```
class VerifyEmail(generics.GenericAPIView):
def get(self, request):
    token = request.GET.get('token')
    print('payload ' + str(settings.SECRET_KEY))
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(jwt=token, key=settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
        print('payload 1 ' + str(payload))
        user = User.objects.get(id=payload['user_id'])
        if not user.is_active:
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
        return Response({'email': 'Successfully activated'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError as e:
        return Response({'error': 'Activations link expired'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except jwt.exceptions.DecodeError as e:
        return Response({'error': 'Invalid Token'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: @Madhura Prasanna, can you maybe explain how you encode the token ?

Comment: @Lobbel I used this to make access token and refresh token `access_token = AccessToken.for_user(user)
            refresh_token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)`

Comment: @Madhura Prasanna, thank you for your reply. But then i would use a Refresh token only  for a verification,isn't that unnecessary ? I could use the built in function from django => default_token_generator .

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Pratik [Charwad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6672256/pratik-charwad) really works, so I will just add the native djangorestframework-jwt alternative, it uses the same jwt library for decoding:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.utils import jwt_decode_handler

decoded_payload = jwt_decode_handler('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MzIxMzg3ODQsImV4cCI6MTUzMjEzOTA4NCwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJwcmF0aWsucHVjc2RAZ21haWwuY29tIiwibXlmIjoxfQ.enG5qiSOPh98YYZBpScHSL5TM8RBz6JhU6uF0l1bZXM')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this `jwt.decode(token,settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])`

Comment: Perfect!, `jwt.decode` isn't accepting None for the `secret and algorithm` value.