# How to decode and verify simple-jwt-django-rest-framework token

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

i am trying to verify and decode simple-jwt-django-rest-framework token.
I know we can use verify api of simple-jwt.
But i want to decode and verify in my views . Below is the current code i am trying:-

```
//in views.py

class home(APIView):
   def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
      print("request is ",request._request)
      verify_token_response = token_verify(request._request)
      print("status_code is ", verify_token_response.status_code)

      if(verify_token_response.status_code == 200):
        jwt_object  = JWTAuthentication() 
        validated_token = jwt_object.get_validated_token(request._request)
        user            = jwt_object.get_user(validated_token)
        print(user)
    
    return Response({
            'status':True, 
            'message':'home'
            })
```

This code is working for me for token validation. It is validating token correctly , but when i am retrieving the valiated_token and user , it giving me error of :-

```
{
    "detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
    "code": "token_not_valid",
    "messages": [
        {
            "token_class": "AccessToken",
            "token_type": "access",
            "message": "Token is invalid or expired"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This answer will help for you [Decode token and verify user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430827/10605995)

Answer (score 15):

You can use  the `JWTAuthentication` class from `rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication` module. it contains a method called
`authenticate(request)` which takes in the request object, checks the
validity of the token and returns both the user associated with the token and the validated token with the decoded claims

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
JWT_authenticator = JWTAuthentication()

# authenitcate() verifies and decode the token
# if token is invalid, it raises an exception and returns 401
response = JWT_authenticator.authenticate(request)
if response is not None:
    # unpacking
    user , token = response
    print("this is decoded token claims", token.payload)
else:
    print("no token is provided in the header or the header is missing")
```

Comment: this is exactly what I need, tks. I need to verify which user requesting.

Answer (score 9):

Basicly any JWT is a result of

1. Payload
2. Secret
3. Encoding algorithm

**Payload** is just hashmap with user identification, role, permission etc.

```py
payload = {
  username: "James Bond",
  roles: ['admin'],
  permissions: ['user | add', 'user | edit'],
  id: 7,
}
```

**Secret** Is a long string like password you have it in your setting.py

```py
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
```

**Encoding algorithm** Is a method for encryption

To decode you must use the same  **SECRET_KEY** used to encode.

```py
import jwt
# Token generated by simple-jwt-django-rest-framework or any
token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiL....";
    
print(jwt.decode(token, config('SECRET_KEY'), algorithms=["HS256"]))
```

You can replace **config('SECRET_KEY')** with "123" or whatever is in your settings.py

Answer (score 4):

I think you should send the RAW_TOKEN and not request._request

```
  if(verify_token_response.status_code == 200):
    jwt_object      = JWTAuthentication() 
    header          = jwt_object.get_header(request)
    raw_token       = jwt_object.get_raw_token(header)
    validated_token = jwt_object.get_validated_token(raw_token)
    user            = jwt_object.get_user(validated_token)
    print(user)
```

Comment: exactly what i needed

Answer (score 2):

When you configure the `rest_framework_simplejwt` authentication, do you have to configure the `SIMPLE_JWT` variable on the file `settings.py`, and there are the `ALGORITHM` and the `SIGNING_KEY` how this:

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    ...

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS512',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    ...
}
```

Where the `SIGNING_KEY` are the `SECRET_KEY`constant in your `settings.py` file.
Then, do you can get the algorithm value in the `ALGORITHM` key at `SIMPLE_JWT` dict. In my case, the algorithm is `'HS512'`.

After know the algorithm, do you have to import the `SIMPLE_JWT` from `settings.py` and do you can use the `decode` method from `jwt` how the example bellow:

```
import jwt
from your_project.settings import SIMPLE_JWT

...

token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC..."
jwt.decode(
   token,
   SIMPLE_JWT['SIGNING_KEY'],
   algorithms=[SIMPLE_JWT['ALGORITHM']],
)
```